# Element: True,False,Maybe,,,

Tags: symbolic

I have a question about `Element[]`

`Element[3/2,Rationals]`

> True       OK

`Element[Sqrt@2,Rationals]`

> False   OK

`Element[Log[4,32],Rationals]`

> True  OK (because it equals 5/2)

`Element[Log[4,33],Rationals]`
$$\frac{\log (33)}{\log (4)}\in \mathbb{Q}$$

> NOT OK because I should get False

So Element "knows" if something is `true` but not if it is `false`
Can anybody explain this?

Comment: from help, under possible issues, it says `When domain membership cannot be decided the Element statement remains unevaluated:`  So Mathematica could not decide. That is what the answer means. Mathematica did not say `False`. It said `I do not know`. Which is OK. Even Mathematica sometimes can't solve a problem.

Comment: @Nasser don't you think that Mathematica should be able to answer this kind of question?

Comment: Please DO NOT use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions. DO add the bugs tag when you verified someone else's question to be about an actual bug. See the tag description for more info. Please fix the tags on this post.

Comment: @Szabolcs Can you please suggest the right tags for this question? What are your thoughts about my question? Finding out if a logarithm is rational or not is pretty easy in maths. Don't you think that Mathematica should be able to deal with such easy problems?

Comment: I think tagging as symbolic computation is appropriate here. I disagree that this is a bug. `Element` does not do much on its own, and can't be used for testing. `FullSimplify[Element[x,set]]` *can* be, and also does not work here. I would call it a missing feature, but not a bug.